# Mysql update a column with removing differences

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update

I don't know how to explain this in words. So please let me say an example.
Suppose the items table sorted by `order` column:

```
| id | name | order |
| 5  |   x  |   1   |
| 2  |   y  |   3   |
| 3  |   z  |   4   |
| 7  |   p  |   8   |
```

I want to update `order` column in a way which each of them has 1 difference with their successive row with keeping the order.
Desired result:

```
| id | name | order |
| 5  |   x  |   1   |
| 2  |   y  |   2   |
| 3  |   z  |   3   |
| 7  |   p  |   4   |
```

Edit:
Selecting row_number() isn't my solution as I want to change orders and I'm not just looking for the row number.

Comment: Why don't you use 'AUTO_INCREMENT'? I think this is what you need.

Comment: @thebrownkid Because if any of rows get deleted I lose the arrangement. I want to fix the gap.

Comment: @thebrownkid Because for a special case I'm in page number x.
The front end sends me an array of items with the page number.
For example page 2 with array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) which are ids of items.
I want to order them. The offset is 10. So I set orders with these values (11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
but if my order column has gaps then it will be not possible to order them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL8, just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
    row_number() over(order by ord) as new_ord
from mytable t
```

This demonstrates that the information can easily be computed on the fly when needed and leads to the finding that storing such derived information might not be a good idea. It is tedious to keep it up to date when new rows are added or deleted.

Instead, you can use the above query, or put it in a view:

```
create view myview as
select t.*,
    row_number() over(order by ord) as new_ord
from mytable t
```

Note: `order` is a language keyword, I used `ord` instead.

If you really need an `update`, for a one-time task for example:

```
update mytable t
inner join (
    select id, row_number() over(order by ord) as new_ord from mytable
) t1 on t1.id = t.id
set t.ord = t1.new_ord
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using view for such requirement as also mentioned in other answer.

If this is the one time activity and if order is unique for each record then you can use the following query which uses corelated sub-query.

```
Update your_table t
Set t.order = (select count(1) 
From your_table tt where tt.order <= t.order);
```

Comment: MySQL does not support such "self-correlated" subquery in  `update` statement. See by yourself: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0405169fbb3ba0e602c4619bc9883bf2.